# Upgrade Backup and Migrate from 2.x to 3.x

Tags: backups

Is it possible to upgrade without losing profile settings?
Or is it simply uninstall 2.x, install 3.x and recreate profile settings?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that upgrade without losing any data.

Comment: Indeed, it does not answer my question. To be more specific: when i try to install 3.x, Drupal says BaM is already installed and refuses to install 3.x when 2.x is present.

Does that mean i have to first uninstall 2.x, install 3.x, and this uninstall/install keeps all my settings and backups? I am a bit surprised i do not find anywhere a text about this upgrade. Maybe i oversee some information or my question is a stupid one. Sorry if that's the case.